# How can I label my html range slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, uislider

I don't use jquery slider. I use bootstrap 3. I want to label my range slider with 0, 500, 1000. I want it to work on mobile, desktop, tablet.

```
.ios-range-slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #D7DEDD;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
}


input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd provide a snippet or a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) since your question is not limited to its CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `media` selectors

e.g.

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    .ios-range-slider {
    }
}


@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
    .ios-range-slider {
    }
}
```

Comment: how will that label it?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily label it, but it makes it so that at the specified screen sizes, certain content shows. This is how most websites create mobile websites. This should create the desired effect.